# How to mount an ext3 partition from an external sd card on android

Tags: applications, sd-card, linux, partitions

I'm trying to run Debian on the Android 4.4 (modded with cyanogenmod) that's installed on my nexus 10 to external sdcard. I'm reading this tutorial :

http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian

I've attached the Leef microSD microUSB Connector to the mini usb port of my nexus 10 as you can see here :

[image: leef connector attached to my nexus 10]

I've created two partitions on the sd card,as explained on the tutorial. The first is formatted with fat fs and the second one with ext3 file system. This is what I did when I've prepared the sd card partitions on the desktop computer :

```
Disk /dev/sdf: 64.0 GB, 64021856256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125042688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004504c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2048    32767999    16382976    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sdf2        32768000   125042687    46137344   83  Linux
```

When I attach the leef connector,only the fat32 partition is recognized by android,but not the ext3. This is the mount points that I see :

[image: android mount points]

To proceed with the tutorial I need to mount the second partition where should be installed the debian OS. How can I do this ? thanks.

Comment: How have you formatted the 2nd partition? mkfs.ext3?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by myself with these commands :

`mount -o rw,remount /`

`mount -t ext4 /dev/block/sda2 /mnt/deb`

Comment: You could try `mount -t auto ...` for both partitions to see if it recognizes the correct fs type.

Comment: mount -t auto didn't work